# I use regex for removing duplicate words in a string

Tags: java, regex, duplicates

but it remove white space. I don't want to remove white space! What should I do?

Original text

> I **like like like** this movie, it was **so so so** **good good
>   good**.

Remove duplicates

> I **likelike** this movie, it was **soso** **goodgood**.

Here is my code:

```
 String result = s.replaceAll("(?i)\\b([a-z]+)\\b(?:\\s+\\1\\b)+", "$1$1");
```

Comment: Why would you use `"$1$1"` as the replacement string, instead of just `"$1"`?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem because i want the result be Like Like Like -----> Like Like

Comment: Like "like like" with a space between?  Like `"$1 $1"` maybe?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem yeah!!!!!! It's work!!! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

As Dawood ibn Kareem points out in the comments, if you want a space between words, why don't you add a space in your replacement pattern, like so:

```
String result = s.replaceAll("(?i)\\b([a-z]+)\\b(?:\\s+\\1\\b)+", "$1 $1");
```

Comment: yeah! I got it.Thanks @Nacimota :D

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but you just need to replace `$1$1` with `$1`.

**EDIT:** It is also mentioned in the comments, by Dawood ibn Kareem.

Comment: I want the result (like like like to like like). That's why I use $1$1.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 *
 * @author Md. Amran Hossain
 */
public class DuplicateWordRemove {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "like like like";
    // TODO code application logic here
    String result = s.replaceAll("(?i)\\b([a-z]+)\\b(?:\\s+\\1\\b)+", "$1");
    System.out.println(""+result);
}
```

}

## Output

Like

Comment: I want the result be ( like like like to like like). What should i do?

Comment: @Shar you need remove duplicate word ... If you remove 1st duplicate word you need to used "$1\f$1" like that: String result = s.replaceAll("(?i)\\b([a-z]+)\\b(?:\\s+\\1\\b)+", "$1\f$1"); output is: like like

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String result = s.replaceAll("(?i)(\\b\\w+\\b)\\s+\\1", "$1");
```

Comment: Thank you I got the answer :D

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

Sorry for posting a second answer, but I just want to ascertain that you get notified of this answer.

```
String h = s.replaceAll("(?i)\\b([a-z]+)\\b((?:\\s+\\1\\b)+)", "$2");
h = h.replaceAll("\\s+", " "));
```

This should remove the last repeated word :)

Comment: Thank you @Coffeehouse Coder :D

Comment: @Shar Anytime bro!